# Removing text between "--" and "\cr"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, newline, streamreader

I would like to remove text between "--" and "\cr".

I'm actually reading out of a file and if the file has a "--" in it, it should remove the "--" along with whatever everything until the "\cr".

I am reading the file line by line.

```
using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    }
}
```

Ive tried using a substring to look for the characters

```
line.Substring(line.IndexOf("--"),line.IndexOf("\cr"));
```

But I am having a problem looking for the delimiters on each line

I was thinking about writing something like this

```
while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Substring(line.IndexOf("--")) // If it has "--"
    {
      //Then remove all text from between the 2 delimiters

    }
}
```

Please help

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Problem solved, although I have come across another problem, I am unable to remove comments between `/* */` as the comments occur on multiple lines. So I need to remove all text between `/* */`.

Any suggestions or help?
Thanks

Comment: That "\cr" looks somewhat strange. If you meant CR as in Carriage Return, it's written "\r", but will be already stripped off by ReadLine, this way just  remove everything from "--" on.

Comment: Thanks eugene, your actually right. It is supposed to be a Carriage Return

Comment: What kind of questions does one have to post to get UpVoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to just use a regex replace on the line:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"--.*$", "");
```

This assumes that whatever you mean with `\cr` is the actual end of the line (which isn't included anyway if you read it with `ReadLine()`), so this removes everything from `--` until the end of the line instead.

To replace `/* ... */` comments too you may use:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"--.*$|/\*.*?\*/", "");
```

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> $a = 'foo bar','foo bar -- some comment','foo /* another comment */ bar'
PS> $a -replace '--.*$|/\*.*?\*/'
foo bar
foo bar
foo  bar
```

Comment: I will try the regex.replace() method. But what does the .*$ mean? Will i have to put that in whenever i want to use a char in regex?

Comment: Your answer worked pretty well, except for now im having a problem with /* */ comments

Comment: Ive managed to remove the '/*' but the '*/' doesnt get removed

Comment: Do they extend over multiple lines?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
line.Substring(line.IndexOf("--"));
```

As Joey as mentioned ReadLine() will never contain Environment.NewLine and \cr correspond to Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 1):

Just to show how to remove the comments from every line in the file. This is one way:

```
var newLines = from l in File.ReadAllLines(path)
               let indexComment =  l.IndexOf("--")
               select indexComment == -1 ? l : l.Substring(0, indexComment);
File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);      // rewrite all changes to the file
```

**Edit**: If you also want to remove all between `/*` and `*/` this is a possible implementation:

```
String[] oldLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
List<String> newLines = new List<String>(oldLines.Length);
foreach (String unmodifiedLine in oldLines)
{
    String line = unmodifiedLine;
    int indexCommentStart = line.IndexOf("/*");
    int indexComment = line.IndexOf("--");

    while (indexCommentStart != -1 && (indexComment == -1 || indexComment > indexCommentStart))
    {
        int indexCommentEnd = line.IndexOf("*/", indexCommentStart);
        if (indexCommentEnd == -1)
            indexCommentEnd = line.Length - 1;
        else
            indexCommentEnd += "*/".Length;
        line = line.Remove(indexCommentStart, indexCommentEnd - indexCommentStart);
        indexCommentStart = line.IndexOf("/*");
    }

    indexComment = line.IndexOf("--");
    if (indexComment == -1)
        newLines.Add(line);
    else
        newLines.Add(line.Substring(0, indexComment));
}

File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);
```

Comment: Hi tim, How would you do that if you want to remove all text between /* "" */. The text inbetween occurs on multiple lines. It is commeting that i want to remove

Comment: @Sigh-AniDe: You haven't mentioned this in your question yet.

Comment: Ive added the question to my question :?

Comment: @Sigh-AniDe: Edited my answer to take `/* "" */` into account.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to ignore lines contaning comments. How about

```
if (!line.StartsWith("--")) { /* do stuff if it's not a comment */ }
```

or even

```
if (!line.TrimStart(' ', '\t').StartsWith("--")) { /* do stuff if it's not a comment */ }
```

to ignore whitespace at the start of the line.

Comment: I didn't get the impression that the lines necessarily *started* with `--`. They wouldn't have used `IndexOf` otherwise.